# How to make cpupower not reset after each restart?

Tags: cpu

I use this command

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set -u 1.5G
```

To make the max CPU frequency to 1.5GHz but after restart it sets it back to default.

How can I set this at boot ?

Answer (score 1):

Any easy and reversible way

Open gedit and make a new blank document, then paste this into it

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set -u 1.5G
```

Now save it as `cpu.sh`, the .sh is very important and run

```
sudo cp ~/cpu.sh /etc/init.d/
```

Make it executable

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/cpu.sh
```

Then run

```
update-rc.d cpu.sh defaults
```

Now this script should run as root on boot

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23603/discussion-on-answer-by-mark-kirby-how-to-make-cpupower-not-reset-after-each-res).

Answer (score 0):

Check out /etc/default/cpupower, ...try adding `max_freq="1.50Hz"`

To detail the steps, run `sudo nano /etc/default/cpupower`, add the above line, then hit ctrl-o to save, and ctrl-x to exit.

/etc/default/ has global config files that are read at boot. Hope that will solve the problem.

Comment: Doesn't work. Could it be that it asks me for password when setting it myself in the terminal ?

Comment: @markkirby `sudo gedit`? Really? Do you want to ruin my good reputation?

Comment: Don't understand, sorry.

Comment: @Ivaylo No, it has nothing to do with sudo. If cpupower doesn't work, try `cpufreq-utils` instead.

Comment: @mikewhatever I was making it as easy as possible for the OP as they expressed they did not understand the answer, whats wrong with gedit ?

Comment: `cpufreq-utils` doesn't work

Comment: @markkirby Much is wrong with [sudo gedit](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2269093), and I make a point of never ever advising it.

Comment: @Ivaylo So, nothing works? I am sory to hear, don't know why. Perhaps double check eveything has been copied correctly.

Comment: @mikewhatever Thanks for that I will avoid it from now on.

Comment: Very strange. The `indicator-cpufreq` is missing from the top bar and when i set the governor to "powersave" it still says that the current policy should be within 2.20 and 2.20.

Comment: Ups, sorry wrong comment :)

Comment: Hi, when i try to edit the file scaling_max_freq and scaling_min_freq it doesn't allow me to save it. Also if i set it myself from the terminal with `sudo cpupower frequency-set -u 1500000` it changes in the file, so logicly it will again reset itself after each boot.

Comment: This is the answer. I wonder why it didn't have any upvote.