# how to setup cpupower at boot time in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: power-management, cpu, systemd

Ubuntu users!

I have a Intel computer running basically as a HTPC machine for years 24/7 and at a certain point in time the Linux kernel started to use the `intel_pstate` driver for my i7 Ivy Bridge (I chose such a high-end CPU to an HTPC because it was the most power efficient in lower frequencies). Since then, I lost the ability to fix the CPU frequency in `indicator-cpufreq` and as this machine stays on all the time I have a higher power consumption than I wanted.

I tried to fix that a few times without success, setting `/sys` stuff manually included, but in my last try I could finally lower the max frequency using `cpupower`:

```
cpupower frequency-set -u clock_freq
```

My question is: Whats is the best way to run this at boot time in Ubuntu 16.04?

Similar questions I found:

[How to permanently set CPU power management to the powersave governor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410860/how-to-permanently-set-cpu-power-management-to-the-powersave-governor) - CPUFreq is considered deprecated and don't change CPU frequencies with `intel_pstate`

[How to make cpupower not reset after each restart?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621184/how-to-make-cpupower-not-reset-after-each-restart) - This is very close, but since Ubuntu 16.04 uses `systemd` it doesn't seem appropriate to me to create a legacy SysV service (I don't even know if it works).

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling - Arch seems to have a `cpupower.service` systemd unit, but I failed to find it in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still need help, then you can do one of the following:

- add your code to **/etc/rc.local** (before `exit 0`), then enter the command `sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service` and reboot
- create a [systemd service](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd)